# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class and -boolForKey: method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Here's [the link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010934)

> boolForKey:
>   Returns the Boolean value associated with the specified key.
>
> -(BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)aKey
>   Parameters
>   aKey
>   A key in the key-value store.
>
> Return Value
>   If a Boolean value is associated with the specified key, that value is returned. If the key was not found, this method returns NO.

So, having spent my last 4 hours, i still can't figure out a way to distinguish these 2 cases in code:

**A)** The return value is NO after setting a boolean value with NO with a specified key

**from:**

**B)** the return value is NO because no such specified key was found!

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `objectForKey:` to see if an object actually exists for that key.

Comment: oh, of course Sebastian, you are right! class reference mislead me. thanks bro :)

Comment: I agree with @Sebastian. boolForKey is great for if statements to determine if a value is set to yes. If it set to YES you do one thing, if it is set to NO or not set at all, you would do another.